# Does RegisterRawInputDevices() block standard key press processing?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I am using RegisterRawInputDevices() to receive WM_INPUT messages of keyboard input, which allows me to identify which keyboard the input was from.  That works great.

However, the input is not actually registering with the form window.  I can see that a key was pressed in the debugger, but the text box on the form never receives any text input.  So, what I'm having a ridiculously hard time figuring out is how to allow normal processing to continue.  It seems like registering the raw input prevents my application from getting it "naturally" so to speak.

I've been digging the internet since yesterday and I haven't found an answer.  So, any input would be appreciated here.

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case (int)WindowsMessages.INPUT:
                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUT));
                uint dwSize = 0;
                Native.GetRawInputData(m.LParam, (uint)RawInputCommand.Input, IntPtr.Zero, ref dwSize, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));
                IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);

                if (Native.GetRawInputData(m.LParam, (uint)RawInputCommand.Input, buffer, ref dwSize, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))) == dwSize)
                {
                    RAWINPUT raw = (RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RAWINPUT));

                    if (raw.header.dwType == RawInputType.Keyboard)
                    {
                        string character = Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeys), raw.data.Keyboard.VKey.ToString()).ToString();

                        switch (raw.data.Keyboard.Message)
                        {
                            case (int)WindowsMessages.KEYDOWN:
                                OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(KeyType.KeyDown, m, character));
                                break;
                            case (int)WindowsMessages.KEYUP:
                                OnKeyUp(new KeyEventArgs(KeyType.KeyUp, m, character));
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Post your `WndProc()` code.

Comment: I added my WndProc() code to my original post.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: If you set up your `RAWINPUTDEVICE` correctly (I suppose so, since you're processing WM_INPUT) with `usUsagePage  = 0x01`, `usUsage = 0x06`, `dwFlags = 0x00000100` and `hwndTarget` to the Window Handle, you are probably just not pre-processing the messages. See: [Control.PreProcessMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.preprocessmessage(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, this CodeProject article might help you: [Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard).

Comment: Jimi - thanks for the quick responses.  I looked at the Control.PreProcessMessage but none of the override functions on the form relating to Process Key/Message are firing.  If I run the form with the RegisterRawInputDevices() uncommented.  The form just doesn't show any key entry anymore.  I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: Jimi - I reread your post and looked at my code, and my flags were set for 0x0100 & 0x0030.  I removed the 0x0030 and that solved the problem.  I had that from a post I came across.    Thanks for your help.

Comment: Suppressing legacy messages is, well, strange in this contex. I'm glad this helped. Anyway, don't discard what I said about pre-processing the messages, It's important. Also, you might find yourself in need to run you application elevated in some cases. Be prepared for that, too.

Comment: Raw Input can monitor input. It provides no way for an application to intercept it, and prevent the system from processing it. If input fails to reach your application, Raw Input can be discarded as a cause.